Integrating the ratio of $2$-norm and $1$-norm of bounded function over bounded domain
Let's assume that for each $t \in [0,1]$, I have bounded functions of the form $f_t: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ all in $L_2$ and for almost all (in Lebesgue sense) $t \in [0,1]$, $\|f_t\|_1$ is positive (but their $\inf$ could be $0$). I am interested in a proof showing that the following quantity is finite, or a counterexample of such $f_t$'s that the following quantity is infinite:
$$ 
\int_0^1 \frac{\|f_t\|_2^2}{\|f_t\|_1^2} dt.
$$
Some thoughts: the bound $\|f_t\|_2^2 < \|f_t\|_\infty \|f_t\|_1$ seems loose for this purpose since it's easy to construct $f_t$ whose $1$-norm is $t$ but these construction does not work to make the original integral unbounded.
Thanks in advance.

Letting $f_t = \chi_{[0, t]}$, we have $\| f_t \|_1^2 = t^2$, $\| f_t \|_2^2 = t$, hence $\frac{\| f_t \|_2^2}{\| f_t \|_1^2} = \tfrac{1}{t}$ and the integral diverges.
